# HorizontalScrollView not scrolling only for Galaxy S2 et S3

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

In my app I have a bottom bar which can have many tabs that i can scroll to them.
in other devices other than the Galaxy S2 and S3 the scroll work great but in Samsung S2 and S3 the scroll doesn't work and so some tabs cannot be reached (see figure).

[image: show where scroll]

here's my code for the bottom bar (in blue in the picture) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/svContainerParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/height_tab_fragment_bottom"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/svContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LanguageContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/FlagLanguage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/english_r" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/svHolder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewTabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/command"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textCommand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cartName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/cart_name"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cartPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0.00 €"
                android:textSize="8sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

so is this a bug in the galaxy? or is it something wrong i'm doing ?(but why it works on all other devices )
here's [the link of the app on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paperpad.HotelMinistere) if someone wish to look this problem.

Comment: I don't know why did someone gave me minus ?!! is this not a question ?

Comment: Don't use `android:layout_gravity` for the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/svHolder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewTabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

try to remove the linear layout and keep the `HorizontalScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Some things weird on your layout:

1) Why do you have two nested horizontal LinearLayouts ? (svContainerParent and svContainer)
Whatever you are trying to do, you can do it with only one.

2) Remove android:gravity="center" from the RelativeLayout. It does not do anything there.

3) Remove the first LinearLayout wrapping your HorizontalScrollView. Put the necessary parameters on the HorizontalScrollView itself instead.

4) And finally, why do you have that RelativeLayout wrapping your ImageView? You would only use a RelativeLayout if you want your view to go on top (or behind) another view (which does not seem to be the case on your screenshots).

I assume one of those cases is causing the problem of not scrolling on some devices. Let me know if it helps!